# Changing legend name in ArcGIS 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, legend

[image: picture]I can't wrap my head around how to change this legend name.
The left picture shows the raster in the Toc with that annoying "VALUE", the centre shows how the legend appears and the right one shows what I see by going to layer properties.

I would just like to omit river_density and VALUE and just display a name I choose for that legend.  The raster was created with the line density tool.

Comment: I have removed the name (river_density)  from the raster in ToC so that it is just a blank space, but <VALUE> underneath remains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way if you to keep the name in the Table of Content and hide it in the legend is to `right-click the legend -> Properties -> Style -> Properties -> General ->` Uncheck the layer name and if you don't want the header "Value", you can also uncheck it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you go to legend properties, followed by the Items tab, you can select the legend Style... This will select which elements get shown in the legend, titles/layers, etc.